# Связывание потоков данных двух программ

Tags: c++, c

Необходимо, что бы первая программа вызвала вторую программу, подменив ей Stdin и Stdout на два файла (из одного считывание, в другой запись). Всё это на СИ или С++ и без использования аргументов командной строки.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду конвейер что ли?

Comment: Смотрите на [dup2/dup3](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html), [fork](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [exec...](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html)

Answer (score 0):

Специально для решения этой вашей задачи существует функция *popen()*  Делаем *man popen* и читаем:

> Функция  popen()  открывает  процесс  следующим  образом: создаёт
>   канал, выполняет fork и вызывает командную оболочку. Так как канал
>   задается однонаправленным, в аргументе  type  может  быть  задан один
>   режим: либо чтение либо запись.

Пример использования:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define EXIT(s) {fprintf(stderr, "%s",s); exit(0);}
#define USAGE(s) {fprintf(stderr, "%s Данные для чтения\n",s); exit(0);}
#define MAX 8192

enum {ERROR=-1,SUCCESS};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  FILE *pipe_writer, *file;
  char buffer[MAX];
  if(argc!=2)
    USAGE(argv[0]);

  if((file=fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
    EXIT("Ошибка открытия файла.........\n");

  if(( pipe_writer=popen("./filter" ,"w")) == NULL)
    EXIT("Ошибка открытия трубы...........\n");

  while(1)
  {
    if(fgets(buffer, MAX, file) == NULL)
    break;
    if(fputs(buffer, pipe_writer) == EOF)
      EXIT("Ошибка записи........\n");
  }
  pclose(pipe_writer);
}
```

В этом примере предполагается, что запуская эту программу, Вы зададите её первым параметром имя файла для обработки. Этот файла считывается данным модулем и по пайпу передаётся программе 'filter' для дальнейшей обработки.